# I want an Distinct Array and should be in a Re-Usable Function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want a distinct array. I couldn't figure it out how it works

---This is my Function---

```
var Array = [2, 0, 1, 9, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4]

function distinctArray(val){
    var newArray=[];
    for(var i=0 ; i < val.length; i++){
        if (newArray.indexOf(val[i]) > -1){
            newArray.push(val[i])
        }
    }
    return newArray
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant to type

```
if (newArray.indexOf(val[i]) == -1) // if it does NOT already exist
```

instead of

```
if (newArray.indexOf(val[i]) > -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use Array.filter() for keeping only element which are unique

```js
var array = [2, 0, 1, 9, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4];
var distinct = array.filter((x,i,arr) => arr.lastIndexOf(x) === i);
console.log(distinct);
```